# Will Kafka allow "unballanced" partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, system-design

One question raised during system design, if message key is selected in the way that it happens too often in the stream of data, does that mean that only one topic partition will be receiving these messages exclusively **even** if that creates disbalance in the way how partitions are filled with data?

Does Kafka have a mechanism to "split" messages with the same key among several partitions, sacrificing order in this case?

Or there are no exceptions in `key -> partition` allocation regardless how that impact size of partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in the topic, the answer is yes, kafka will allow unbalanced partitions.

You can define your own partioner class to decide where the messages would be sent to, in default architecture it is using murmur2 algorithm to decide where to send each key , so it will have same keys in the same partition   if your use case is not requiring ordering between the events you might not need to send key at all, and than the messages would be distributed across the partitions, in last updates kafka "batch" messages sent from producer to same partition to have even better throughput...

To make it clear , kafka does not require you to send a key for a message